# Displaying the currently playing item in a jwplayer 6 playlist in a <div> - worked in jwPlayer 5

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events, jwplayer, livecode

I love the new jwplayer 6 and I have the commercial version so I can brand it. I had everything I wanted using version 5 (including catching the 'onplaylistITme' event) - but it was time to move to 6 for the wider compatibility and the logo display.

Here is the player running on the jwPlayer 5 code. Note the song title displayed at the top.

---

[version 5 of jwPlayer - this shows what I want](http://media.barncard.com/audio/history/howdy-moon-6/audio.irev)

---

The relevant section is this little Javascript handler that takes the event created by the first playing of a list item:

```
    <div id="playlistiteminfo"></div>
<div id="container" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
        'flashplayer': '<?rev put gPlayerParamsA[jwplayerSWF] ?>',
        height: <?rev put gPlayerParamsA[playerHeight] ?>,
        width: <?rev put gPlayerParamsA[playerWidth] ?>,
        logo: {
            file: '<?rev put gPlayerParamsA[watermarkLoc] ?>',
            link: 'http://barncard.com'
            },
        'playlist': [{
<?rev

put tPlayListP  -- JAVASCRIPT PLAYLIST CREATED EARLIER INSERTED HERE

?>
 }],
'playlist.position': "<?rev put gPlayerParamsA[playListPosition] ?>",
    'playlist.size': <?rev put gPlayerParamsA[playListSize] ?>,
    'controlbar.position': 'bottom',
    skin:'<?rev  put gPlayerParamsA[skinSWF] ?>',  
    repeat: 'list',
    events: {
    onPlaylistItem: function(evt) {
        var playlistitem = this.getPlaylistItem();
        var infodiv = document.getElementById("playlistiteminfo");
        infodiv.innerHTML = "";
        infodiv.innerHTML += playlistitem.title;
        }
    }

});
        <?rev
        if gPlayerParamsA["single_play_index"] is a number
            then
        ?>
            jwplayer().playlistItem(<?rev put gPlayerParamsA["single_play_index"] ?>);
        <?rev
        end if
        ?>
</script>
```

Going to version 6 broke a lot of things, and the syntax is simpler and cleaner but different but I was able to get it all working again except the event code listed above. It should be noted that I am using Livecode server-side instead of PHP but there is no issue with that.

---

[version 6 jwPlayer version](http://media.barncard.com/audio/history/howdy-moon-6/audio.irev)

---

```
<div id="container" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
        height: <?rev put gPlayerParamsA[playerHeight] ?>,
        width: <?rev put gPlayerParamsA[playerWidth] ?>,
        logo: {
            file: "<?rev put gPlayerParamsA[watermarkLoc] ?>",
            link: "http://barncard.com",
            position: "bottom-left"
            },
        playlist: [{
<?rev

put tPlayListP  -- JAVASCRIPT PLAYLIST CREATED EARLIER INSERTED HERE

?>
     }],
     displaytitle: "false",
     listbar: {
         position: "right",
         size: <?rev put gPlayerParamsA[playListSize] ?>,
     }

});
        <?rev
        if gPlayerParamsA["single_play_index"] is a number
            then
        ?>
            jwplayer().playlistItem(<?rev put gPlayerParamsA["single_play_index"] ?>);
        <?rev
        end if
        ?>
</script>
```

So when I add this code snippet to the above code after  postion: "right", it breaks the whole player and doesn't work.

```
repeat: 'list',
    events: {
    onPlaylistItem: function(evt) {
        var playlistitem = this.getPlaylistItem();
        var infodiv = document.getElementById("playlistiteminfo");
        infodiv.innerHTML = "";
        infodiv.innerHTML += playlistitem.title;
        }
```

So:

1. I can't tell if the EVENTS are or are not working in jwPlayer 6 or not - some web posts indicate that they are not.
2. or it's my minimal understanding of the proper syntax.

I'm hoping that there's someone out there that has successfully done this or has a work-around…

Comment: In JW6, change, repeat: 'list', to repeat: 'true',

Comment: Awesome, no problem! :) I will add as an answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

In JW6, change:

`repeat: 'list',`

To:

```
repeat: 'true',
```

That should do the trick.